# how do i redirect after logout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, redirect

I've placed login status control on a page, and placed under LogoutPageUrl to Default.aspx.

However, after I logout it redirects me to

```
...default.aspx?ReturnUrl= some stuff
```

So, it does not redirect me directly to default.aspx. How do I force 'real' redirect ?

Thanks

EDIT:, solved: this in linkbutton:

```
        Session.Abandon()
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
```

Comment: and what is the problem with that? you still load the Default.aspx right?

Comment: The problem is that this extra url points to previous page which is not available to some roles, so some users may not login to the site.

Comment: If you solved your problem, post the solution as a response and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place linkbutton and this code onCLick()

```
Session.Abandon()
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
```

Comment: use web.config value is better than hard code:
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, false); //redirect to website defaulturl